Change Default Port Pulseaudio
Good morning
I've been trying for several hours and it may be time to ask for help.
I want to change the default port in pulseaudio to bluetooth headphones instead of the laptop built-in speakers.
The GUI doesn't save my settings when I change them and the pavucontrol get stuck at establishing connection when i try to run it as root.
I'm using ubuntu 22.04
Any help appreciated

Please edit your question and add details about your Ubuntu version.
